# Gson - query for registered type adapters?

Tags: java, gson

Is there a way to query a `GsonBuilder` to find out which classes have a registered `JsonSerializer` associated with it? I could probably keep track of it myself, but it would be nice if the data was already available in `GsonBuilder`. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.

You can use the `getAdapter()` methods in the `Gson` class to get the adapter for a specific type, so you could check for any specific one ... but there's not a way to return a list of all of them.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I tried using `getAdapter()` but the returned class doesn't seem to want to match an `instanceof` one of my `JsonSerializer<?>` classes... I'll post anything else I may find.

Comment: Ugh, so ... yeah, it's not going to because it's a generic and there's no way to get the type from it. I was thinking along the lines of it throwing an exception if the adapter isn't registered.